# How to retrieve MAX Turntime of Top Two earliest date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I construct a query to receive the MAX TurnTime **per ID** of the first 2 rounds? Rounds being defined as minimum Beginning_Date to mininmum End_Date of an ID. Without reusing either of the dates for the second round Turn Time calculation.

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of the "without reusing..." in the last sentence ? Is that something already reflected in the data or an important part of the answer?

Comment: Its in order to make sure the date from a previous round is not used. All dates should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` . . . twice:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by turn_time desc) as seqnum_turntime
      from (select d.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by id order by beginning_end desc) as seqnum_round
            from data d
           ) d
      where seqnum_round <= 2
     ) d
where seqnum_turntime = 1;
```

The innermost subquery gets the first two rounds.  The outer subquery gets the maximum.

You could express this without window functions as well:

```
select top (1) with ties d.*
from data d
where d.beginning_date <= (select d2.beginning_date
                           from data d2
                           where d2.id = d.id
                           offset 1 fetch first 1 row only
                          )
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by turntime desc);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Where is the 'D2' coming from? Also I am getting a 'Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 99
Incorrect syntax near 'offset'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 99
Invalid usage of the option first in the FETCH statement.' from the second query...

Comment: @user13518500 . . . That is a table alias -- that was lacking its table name.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  ID
 ,turn_time
 ,beginning_date
 ,end_date
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    ID
   ,MAX(turn_time) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY BeginningDate ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS turn_time --Maximum turn time of the current row and preceding row
   ,MIN(BeginningDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY BeginningDate ROWS BETWEEN  1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS beginning_date --Minimum begin date over current row and preceding row (could also use LAG)
   ,end_date
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY BeginningDate) AS Turn_Number
  FROM
    <whatever your table is>
) turn_summary
WHERE
  Turn_Number = 2
```

Comment: Should mention that while the answer provided by Gordon below *will work* it would not be advisable for large datasets as it will require the data to be sorted twice (or selected twice).  This solution selects the data once and sorts at most one time (no sorting required if the table is organized by id, beginningdate).

Comment: HI bbaird, thanks for your help. When using the query you provided I receive an error message of  "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'." any idea what the issue may be ?

Comment: Sorry, had a syntax error (should have been `ROWS BETWEEN` not `ROWS`.  Fixed in answer.